# ROS2 Humble Executable not found

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to make a turtlesim script in python,
first of all what is difference between "source .../install/setup.bash" ( this works)
and  "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash" ( this doesn't work, it shows package not found)
after this when I am running the python script
( I have included Shebang line "#!/usr/bin/env python3")it is showing no executable found, even after execution permission ( chmod +x <script_name>.py)
[image]

Comment: In the future, make sure to tell us which Operating System and version you are using. But even without that info, @JRTG 's answer is still the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install according to the [official install instructions](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html), and then to follow the [tutorials](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials.html).

They explain how to create a package, source the ROS install and your own package, etc.